# Multiple Adobe Analytic tools in Adobe DTM - how do I only have one fire at a time?

Tags: adobe-analytics

I have multiple instances of Adobe Analytics in the same Adobe DTM web property. They all go to different report suites. I'd like to create a page load rule so that the data is only reported to one report suite for any given page. So far the page load rules that I have created are causing the AA data to report to all of the report suites. Does anyone have any idea to get them to only fire to one at a time?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to set DTM to suppress the call for an event based rule or direct call rule but currently it is not possible to do it with a page load rule within the DTM built-in interface.

Some things you can do:

1) Combine your Adobe Analytics instances into a single instance. Is there a particular reason you are using multiple instances of Adobe Analytics? I know you mentioned they are for separate report suites, but are they also for separate Adobe Analytics instances altogether? If not, is it because they are completely separate implementations with different variables and logic assigned for them? If the only thing different between them is report suite id, then you should combine them and write some logic to pop relevant report suite id(s) for `s.account`.

2) Make use of [`s.abort`](http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/sc/implement/abort.html) to suppress the calls. If your code version is H25.3+ or you are using AppMeasurement then you can set `s.abort` to `true` to make the next Adobe Analytics request (`s.t` or `s.tl` call) be cancelled. Note that this may only be feasible if your instances are all using separate namespaces.. if you are just outputting several instances of code all under the same namespace, you will have issues. Also, if you are doing that, then you may also have issues as far as variables carrying over to other instances.  But in any case, basically within your page load rule you'd add a rule condition where criteria is Data:Custom and then you'd write js logic to determine which one(s) you don't want to pop and set `[namespace].abort=true;` for each of them.  Then `return true` at the end to make sure the condition is always true.

Or, you can set `s.abort=true;` within the **Custom Page Code** section for each Adobe Analytics instance you want to suppress in the page load rule. There are various other methods for popping `s.abort` but hopefully you get the picture.  Which one is best just depends on how all your stuff is actually setup.

3) Pop the Adobe Analytics tags as a regular tag instead of a Tool. Remove them as a tool and put them as a **Javascript / Third Pary Tag** within the page load rule. This includes the core lib code and anything else you may have in the Tool config section. This also means outputting the "trigger" (`s.t` call).  Make a separate one for each one and then you can make conditions for them to pop.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Crayon's answer, you can also choose a custom code implementation in the Library Management section of the tool configuration settings. You will have to paste in the s_code contents and check the box that says "Set report suites using custom code below"

Then, you can use whatever logic you want to set a variable in the code that directs data to the report suites.

```
if(document.location.href == "http://www.mypage1.com"){
    s_account = "rsid_1";
}else{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Brett's answer -  with rare exception, I let Adobe manage the analytics file. However, you can use the customize page code section within the Adobe Analytics tool configuration to deploy plugins or set the report suite ID dynamically. Here's an example I commonly use:

```
var suiteid;
var enviro;
var getURL = window.location.href

// Set RSID based on URL
if (getURL.indexOf('myURL.com') != -1) 
{
suiteid = 'rsidproduction';
s.linkInternalFilters = 'javascript:,mailto:,tel:,' + window.location.host;
enviro = 'prod';
}
else
{
suiteid = 'rsidstaging';
s.linkInternalFilters = 'javascript:,mailto:,tel:,' + window.location.host;
enviro = 'dev';
}
s.account = suiteid;
```

This is an easy way to dynamically change the RSID and keep the analytics file managed by Adobe. I also blogged about this here: [Managing your RISD Dynamically](http://www.searchdiscovery.com/blog/managing-multi-suite-tagging-implementation-adobedtm/)

Comment: I'm not sure this addresses OP's question.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood. I'm suggesting that multiple instances of AA is not necessary nor is it recommended. One way around this is to dynamically send the right data to the right RSID at the right time within a single AA instance.This can be done within the custom code section using my code example above.