# Sitecatalyst - DTM - Direct call rules - clear sticky variables

Tags: javascript, html, adobe, sticky, adobe-analytics

https://i.stack.imgur.com/elGJz.jpg

Hi,
I'm using Direct call rule inside DTM. I'm clicking on a href link (opens in a new window).
I want to remove/clear the eVars and events associated with the click. I've used custom page code to clear the values.

### Direct call rule 1> Adobe analytics Tracking setting :

s.tl(); - does NOT increment a pageview;

### Direct call rule 1 > Adobe analytics> Inside custompagecode:

```
s.eVar12 = dataLayer.testString;
s.events="event2,event16,event19,event22";
s.tl(this,'o','testClick');
s.events="";
s.eVar12="";
return true;
```

### The problem:

I have used s.tl() function inside custom page code, which triggers (pe=lnk_o), and by default the direct call rule again triggers(pe=lnk_o). I'm seeing "pe=lnk_o" being triggered twice.

How do I clear sticky variables in Direct call rule and without duplicating the request?

Comment: Some things you can do:

2) Make use of s.abort to suppress the calls. 

Or, you can set s.abort=true; within the Custom Page Code section for each Adobe Analytics instance you want to suppress in the page load rule. 
3) Pop the Adobe Analytics tags as a regular tag instead of a Tool. Remove them as a tool and put them as a Javascript / Third Pary Tag within the page load rule. This includes the core lib code and anything else you may have inToolconfigsection. This also means outputting the "trigger" (s.t call).  - Thank you Crayon Violent (http://stackoverflow.com/users/184595/crayon-violent)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25063665/multiple-adobe-analytic-tools-in-adobe-dtm-how-do-i-only-have-one-fire-at-a-ti/25068130#25068130 answered by Crayon Violent

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26609400/omniture-events-is-not-firing-sending-data-via-dtm-when-using-s-tl-tracking-meth <- thanks to Crayon Violent

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the double calls because of the use of s.tl() within your code. You are correct in your assumption.